# Sort in a multi dimentional array

Tags: php

I have this array in PHP:

```
foreach($rss_items as $item) :
    $contenu[] = array (
        "auteur" => $author,
        "date" => $item->get_date(),
        "contenu" => $item->get_content()
    );
```

At the end, my array is composed of 6 parts, which everyone contains the 3 variable above.
My question is: How can I sort the array by date and using the strtotime because it's easier to sort with this function.

```
strtotime($item->get_date());
```

Comment: are you able to modify the array as you create it? is it from a database? etc; details please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`usort`](http://php.net/usort) to sort based on your own callback function.

```
usort($contenu, function($a, $b){
    $aSort = strtotime($a['date']);
    $bSort = strtotime($b['date']);

    if($aSort === $bSort) return 0;
    return ($aSort < $bSort) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

NOTE: This will only work in PHP 5.3+.  If you have 5.2 or lower, you can use [`create_function`](http://php.net/create_function).

```
usort($contenu, create_function('$a, $b','
    $aSort = strtotime($a["date"]);
    $bSort = strtotime($b["date"]);

    if($aSort === $bSort) return 0;
    return ($aSort < $bSort) ? -1 : 1;
'));
```

Comment: but my array is multidimentionnal so the $a['date] must be $a[someThing]['date']
And why create a variable $aSort and $bSort ?

Comment: `$contenu` is the array you want to sort, its values are arrays that contain `'date'` fields.  This should work.

Comment: Thanks, it's work. I still have problems, but there are minor.
Thanks a lot bro !

Comment: @Zaidar: `$aSort` and `$bSort` is what we are sorting on.  There was a typo in the code, I fixed it.